# At one's wit's end

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

I want to know if I'm using the idiom "at one's wits end" correctly?

> I was **at my wit's end** trying to figure out how river rejuvenation shapes landforms when, fortunately, I stumbled across a YouTube video which provided a clear explanation.

I am confused about the context in which to use the expression. I thought maybe my problem was not perplexing enough that warranted its use.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds correct.  You were getting stressed about your inability to find the information about river rejuvenation (wits end).  The situation was resolved when you found a youtube video (no longer at wits end).